# label vector line with multiple attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, labeling, qgis-1

I have a line with two 2 attributes. I would like to display both information along with the line in frequent interval, one info above the line and the other is below the line. I am working in QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa software.

Comment: What software are you using? Without this crucial detail, we can't answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am using QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa.

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about what you would like to achieve? It does not fell like vector fields in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field or http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-78.html

Answer (score 1):

You can label the first attribute above the line using the usual way, then duplicate the layer and change the labelling to beneath the line.

I`m not sure if this was already implemented in Lisboa. If not, I suggest an update to QGIS 2.2

Alternatively, you can make a label across 2 lines with something like  `"operator"  || '/n' ||  "ref"` , centered on the line. You have to add the `/n` separator in the Formatting tab.

Comment: To generalise on the answer: Data you wish to use from attribute table, is obtained by putting the column name between double quotation marks, fixed text between single quotes, and the || acts as a 'string-join' or concatenation. For example, to label links is a sewage system, i have labels as follows: "shape"||"height"||'/'||"width" , which leads to labels like EGG700/1500 , based on multiple attributes of the links in the network.